# Chef : Opsworks : run rake task

Tags: rake, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

My objective is to execute a rake task on my apps running in Opsworks.
It appears to me that my opsworks cookbook is not running rake from the correct directory.

How can I tell the cookbook to run in the app home dir (so it can pick up the Gemfile)?
Do I need to specify an RAILS_ENV?

My cookbooks default.rb:

```
Chef::Log.info("****** Audit Photo URLS : Running Rake Task ******")
execute "rake audit:audi_image_urls" do
    command "bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls"
end
```

Errors from Opsworks log:

```
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] ERROR: execute[rake audit:audi_image_urls] (auditphoto::default line 3) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '10'
---- Begin output of bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls ----
STDOUT: Could not locate Gemfile
STDERR: 
---- End output of bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls ----
Ran bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls returned 10
[2014-11-28T18:36:33+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`execute` resource](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html) can take a [`cwd` attribute](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html#attributes) for the working directory from which the command is run.

```
execute "rake audit:audi_image_urls" do
  command       "bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls"
  cwd           '/over/there'
  environment   'RAILS_ENV' => 'production'
end
```

### OpsWorks *Deploy* events and *Execute Recipes* commands

#### Chef 11

OpsWorks populates [`node[:deploy]['appshortname']`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-deploy.html) for *Deploy* events and *Execute Recipes* stack commands to house each applications configuration. With this data you could use:

```
execute "rake audit:audi_image_urls" do
  command       "bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls"
  cwd           node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:deploy_to]
  user          node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:user]
  group         node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:group]
  environment(  { 'RAILS_ENV' => node[:deploy]['appshortname'][:rails_env] } )
end
```

You may want to source [`:environment_variables`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-json-deploy.html#attributes-json-deploy-app-environment) for the `environment` if you have anything related configured there.

#### Chef 12

[From the AWS stack settings docco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-to-data-bags.html)

> In Chef 12 Linux, stack settings are available as [Chef data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html) and are accessed only through Chef search. Data bags are stored on AWS OpsWorks Stacks instances in a set of JSON files in the `/var/chef/runs/run-ID/data_bags` directory, where run-ID is a unique ID that AWS OpsWorks Stacks assigns to each Chef run on an instance. Stack settings are no longer available as Chef attributes, so stack settings can no longer be accessed through the Chef node object. For more information, see the [AWS OpsWorks Stacks Data Bag Reference.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bags.html)

```
app = search("aws_opsworks_app").first

execute "rake audit:audi_image_urls" do
  command       "bundle exec rake audit:audi_image_urls"
  cwd           app['app_source']['deploy_to']
  user          app['app_source']['user']
  group         app['app_source']['group']
  environment(  { 'RAILS_ENV' => app['app_source']['rails_env'] } )
end
```

#### Other events and commands

It looks like OpsWorks runs a little differently to a normal Chef server and supplies it's own JSON blob to a local chef instance for each run which means (as you mentioned) the `:deploy` attributes will be missing for other events/commands Amazon chooses not to supply JSON for.

It might be possible, but very hacky and prone to breakage, to populate the `:deploy` attributes from the last JSON file that contains deploy state: `{"deploy": { "app_name": { "application": "app_name" }` in `/var/lib/aws/opsworks/chef`

You would also need to source the `deploy::default` attributes after that JSON load to fill in any [defaults](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/deploy/attributes/deploy.rb#L49-L115).

Comment: is it possible to derive things like the app deploy dir and rails env rather than have to set ```cwd``` and ```environment``` attributes?

Comment: You normally set config items as [attributes](http://docs.getchef.com/attributes.html) and plug them into recipes as variables `node['app']['foo']['dir']` or `node['app']['foo']['env']`. Assuming Chef is deploying your rails app, where are these set for the deploy?

Comment: so I have been using the opsworks default deploy recipes only, this is my first custom one and it appears running it as a custom recipe (not as part of a deploy) does not expose the attributes I need. So I would have to make a seperate recipe (with environment specific attributes) for each environment? Fascinating.

Comment: add : environment new_resource.environment to the execute block to automatically derive the environment variables from the specific application

Comment: @mconlin yeah i just noticed that. how are you triggering your cookbook/recipe? Can you run it with the `execute_recipes` stack command?

Comment: yep, I am running it via opsworks>run command>execute recipes>name::default.

Comment: nice, the key is that "deploy" attributes from opsworks are available even in non-deploy runs via execute_recipe.. thats what I didnt understand!

Comment: I think that needs to be `cwd "#{node[:deploy]['application'][:deploy_to]}/current"`

Comment: This has changed in chef 12, refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/attributes-to-data-bags.html

Comment: Thanks @NavaneethPk. I've added a Chef12 example from the docco. Does it look ok? I don't have an env to check.